# QTProcess finished() signal triggered without closing external application

Tags: c++, qt

I´m trying to open an external game from qt during a certain period of time. After the application is closed or the time is up, a message is displayed on my GUI.

However when I run the external game, minimize the game´s window (on fullscreen) to check the time remaining and then enter the game again, the finished() signal is triggered as if I have closed the game.

Can anyone tell me how to stop this signal from triggering when the external .exe is minimized?

this is my code

```
  QProcess *myProcess = new QProcess(this);
   connect(myProcess, SIGNAL(finished(int, QProcess::ExitStatus)), this, SLOT(gameClosed(int, QProcess::ExitStatus)));



  myProcess->setWorkingDirectory("C://Program Files (x86)//Sins of a Solar Empire Rebellion");
  myProcess->start(C://Program Files (x86)//Sins of a Solar Empire Rebellion//Sins of a Solar Empire Rebellion.exe,QStringList() << "",QIODevice::ReadWrite);
```

Comment: That's really weird.are you sure the game isn't restarting itself or something like that? Does its PID change?

Comment: In pretty sure the game does not restart because I get back just where I am befor minimizing. However I have no idea how to check or what a PID is.

Comment: You can check [this](http://superuser.com/questions/914782/how-do-you-list-all-processes-on-the-command-line-in-windows) topic for retrieving the _Process IDs_. Then check the PID of your game before and after minimizing it.

Comment: I do not know that game, but it could be you are not actually running the game but some sort of launcher which actually runs the game, if that is the case I have a couple of ideas to suggest.

Comment: Thanks for the answers.Bowdzone:  i checked the PID but they dont't change at all. Marco: This game in particular does not have a launcher but I might come across a game like that so I would really like to read your ideas.